# Taglocity install error

Tags: installation, microsoft-outlook, plugins

When I run the installer for both Taglocity 2 and 3, during the installation I get the following error:

> Error 1001: Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
>
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorException:
>
> Configuration system failed to initalize.

When I try to continue with the installation by clicking OK, a dialog appears with the title *ADX Loader* with the message:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

Clicking *OK* causes the installation to roll back.

Does anyone know what the problem is or how to fix it? I’m using Outlook 2007 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like .NET 2.0 or later is not properly installed. Try repair it http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306160